# Django tutorial - no errors for sqlite3 but tables are not showing up

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm following the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial02/) and after running `python manage.py migrate`, the migration seems to run successfully. This is the output:

```
(base) ➜  django_test git:(master) ✗ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

And `db.sqlite3` is created within the `django_test` directory. However, when I try to list the tables, I'm returned with nothing in sqlite3:

```
(base) ➜  ~ sqlite3 db.sqlite3
SQLite version 3.40.1 2022-12-28 14:03:47
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
```

Django version is 4.2.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `sqlite3 path/to/your/db/file`

Comment: @JPG that worked. Could you explain why the tutorial suggestion didn't work for me even though I was running the command in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create superuser if you didn't (To see data in `/admin` page. )
2. If you use admin panel don't forget to register the models.
3. Or you can use `shell` that's also show the database table and items,

All you need first - insert some data too in the table.